# Writting SQL code with using count and gorup_concat

Tags: mysql, count, procedure, group-concat

I've already read every post with the similarly title but didn't find right answer. 
What I really need to do is to count some data from MySQL table and then do group_concat because I got more than one row.

 My table looks like this 
[image]

 and here is how I tried to run the query

```
SELECT 
    count(cal.day) * 8,
    w.name
    FROM claim as c 
    RIGHT JOIN calendar as cal ON c.id = cal.claim_id
    RIGHT JOIN worker as w ON c.worker_id = w.id
    GROUP BY c.id
    ORDER BY w.name asc
```

But I get for some workers more than one row and I can't group_concat them because of count(). I need this for mysql procedure I've making so please help me if you can. 
I hope I've gived you enough informations

Edit for Dylan:

See the difference in output 
GROUP BY w.id 
[image]

GROUP BY c.id
[image]

Comment: Removed `sql-server` tag

Comment: why `GROUP BY c.id`, not `GROUP BY w.id`?

Comment: @DylanSu see difference in edit one user have more months or one.

Comment: The result for `GROUP BY w.id` seems more reasonable.

Comment: What is the desired result? And what is the goal, in plain English?

Comment: It looks but I need by c.id, I have a request to do like that

Comment: You cannot group only by `d` columns because you have `w.name` in the `SELECT` clause. You must also group by `w.id` (or by `c.worker_id`) to get correct results. Otherwise the values of `w.name` returned by the query are [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: *"My table looks like this"* -- which table? The query uses three tables.

Comment: @axiac This is a HR system I'm making, these are tables for vacations, in claim table I get informations about vacation claim, when it's enabled I'm putting it in calendar table and parsing it day by day(that's why calendar table looks like this) because of view, than in report I need to count spended hours(8 hours of work day) on vacation so I need to multiply the days and working hours, but you can have vacations in several month so they need to be filtered like that. I hope you've understand it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really need here worker table, I've just set it here becouse of better view, I get also same results without workers but it's easier to figure out what it is.

Comment: You still didn't explain what do you want to get. The number of hours spent in vacation for each worker? Where is `GROUP_CONCAT()` involved in this? I think you should `INNER JOIN claims`, not `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does'not allow two aggregate functions used together, like `GROUP_CONCAT(COUNT(...))`.

Therefore, we can use a `sub-query` to work around as below.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.cnt_cal_day) as cnt_days,
    t.name
FROM
( 
    SELECT 
        count(cal.day) * 8 as cnt_cal_day,
        w.name
    FROM claim as c 
    RIGHT JOIN calendar as cal ON c.id = cal.claim_id
    RIGHT JOIN worker as w ON c.worker_id = w.id
    GROUP BY c.id
    ORDER BY w.name asc
) t
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is still not clear for me, I try to guess what you need.

This query:

```
SELECT 
    w.name,
    COUNT(cal.day) * 8 AS nb_hours
FROM worker w
  LEFT JOIN claim c ON w.id = c.worker_id
  INNER JOIN calendar cal ON c.id = cal.claim_id
GROUP BY w.id
ORDER BY w.name ASC
```

returns the names of all workers and, for each one, the number of hours of vacation approved for them.

If you use `LEFT JOIN calendar` instead you will get the number of hours of vacation claimed by each worker (approved and not approved). In order to separate them you should make the query like this:

```
SELECT 
    w.name,
    c.approved,           # <---- I assumed the name of this field
    COUNT(cal.day) * 8 AS nb_hours
FROM worker w
  LEFT JOIN claim c ON w.id = c.worker_id
  LEFT JOIN calendar cal ON c.id = cal.claim_id
GROUP BY w.id, c.approved
ORDER BY w.name ASC
```

This query should return 1 or 2 rows for each worker, depending on the types of vacation claims they have (none, approved only, not approved only, both). For workers that don't have any vacation claim, the query returns `NULL` in column `approved` and `0` in column `nb_hours`.